# Jenkins projects lost SonarQube build step after reinstall the plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, sonarqube5.3

While trying to upgrade SonarQube plugin from 2.2.1 to 2.4, it failed and the plugin is gone. I had to uninstall 2.4 and reinstall 2.3. Now all the SonarQube Analysis Step disappeared from all projects. I can see it's still in the config.xml, but can't see from the web UI. I tried:

1. Reload configuration from disk
2. Manually change from plugin="sonar@2.2.1" to plugin="sonar@2.3" in the config.xml
3. Uninstall and reinstall 2.2.1, reload from disk
4. Manually add the step, compare the result conf.xml to the original, there is no different at all for this step.

Still can't see the step in the job. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by restarting Jenkins.